# What international calling card can be purchased online?

Tags: communication

I'm currently traveling across Europe, making stops in Barcelona, Rome, Paris, and Amsterdam. I need a calling card that I can use to make calls within Europe, as well as be able to call the states. I tried searching on Google for a calling card; but having a hard time separating SEO spam from genuinely good online cards.

So I though I'd ask here for any recommendations for a calling card that can be used for Intra-Europe as well as Europe to U.S. calls that could be purchased online.

Comment: Updated the question to be less subjective. I think the question is good.

Comment: What kind of device are you hoping to make the calls from? Payphones? Mobiles? Landline phones in friends houses? Computers? (It'll affect what your best option is likely to be)

Comment: @VMAtm: Yes I much prefer massaging them into shape to shutting them down. But I like to warn them due to some surprsing shut down questions in the recent past.

Answer (score 6):

I've used [RebTel](http://www.rebtel.com/) successfully for that. They have local access numbers, apps for your phone, and international access numbers.