# European roaming data provider, which SIM cards can be purchased on-line / in Poland

Tags: europe, poland, communication, mobile-operators

(*question similar to [this](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/801/15281), but focused on data plans and SIM cards with purchase on-line or in Poland*)

I'm about to travel across the Europe (mainly and maybe some other parts of the world) and I'd like to prepare myself for having uninterrupted access to the Internet through my travel. It is quite easy, when you go by the plane, as you can by in-country SIM cards directly in the airport. But, when you're going to travel by car or train, you must have SIM card with you, once you're near the border.

Thus, I'm looking for any European (world-wide) mobile carrier which would offer, mostly data plans oriented SIM cards, that can be purchased on-line and sent to Poland or bought directly in Poland.

I did some research here or there and so far I managed to find two options:

1. [Lycamobile](http://www.lycamobile.com/) offers separate SIM cards for each country, where they offer their services.
2. Multi-country operators like [Maxroam](http://www.maxroam.com/) or [Truphone](http://www.truphone.com/) which offers one SIM card for all countries.

For some reasons I consider multi-country solution (second option) as less interesting. Mainly because most of these offers are call-centered and prices for just data plans aren't too good. And I don't want to pay for something I won't be using (calls, text, MMS etc.).

I'd normally go with Lycamobile, but they (again) offer plans that have prices mainly call-oriented plus my initial contact shown some technical issues with getting SIM cards from other countries<sup>1</sup>.

So I'd be happy to read about some alternatives with data transfer oriented offers that can send SIM cards to Poland without problems or which SIM cards can be bought directly in Poland.

<sup>1</sup><sub>You have to order each country-specific SIM card separately as they seem to be not willing to send many cards at once</sub>

Answer (score 2):

If you intend primarily to use you smartphone to chat, you could take a look at [Chatsim](http://www.chatsim.com). According to it's website:

> ChatSim connects all your ChatApps around the world. This way you can chat free of charge and without any limits with WhatsApp, Telegram, Facebook Messenger, WeChat, Viber, LINE, QQ and all other instant messaging Apps.
>   With only € 10 you have unlimited words and emoji for a year.

They also [mention](http://www.chatsim.com/en/buy-now) that they will "deliver it wherever you are for free.". I suppose this includes Poland.

Chatsim also has voice plans, but those are out of the scope of your question.

Disclosure: I am **not** in any way affiliated with Chatsim. I never even used it, just read about it in a magazine and it seemed like a good choice.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm going to accept it, if there will be no better answer. However, as in question, I'm looking for a pure data plan, not tighten or limited to any particular application. I need to transfer data for my company's own applications, which is far beyond scope of chatting.

Answer (score 2):

You could give [GO-SIM](http://www.gosim.com/europe-sim-card.html) a try, they have a European SIM card. As with other multi-country operators, it's call-based rather than data based, but it will save you the time and effort of buying a new SIM in each country you visit. They also have a [Data SIM](http://www.gosim.com/data-sim-card.html), but this may not work in every country in Europe.

Comment: Are you in any way affiliated with these guys ?

Answer (score 0):

It may not be a perfect answer as I cannot figure out how to get SIM card before (You can try to do it somwhere near the border), but here's an offer of one of most popular networks in Poland - ***PLAY***:
http://www.play.pl/en/
They seem to have a nice offer of unlimited internet access.
You can try other networks: ***Orange***, ***T-Mobile*** or ***PLUS*** as well. I believe You can buy their starter packs (SIM cards) in almost every shop.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However I'm a Polish citizen, so I have uninterrupted access to Play network and their SIM cards. I'm looking (and asking about) for a non-Polish mobile carrier, which SIM cards I can order to Poland (in particular, or on-line in general) and to use them once I leave Poland.